# How can I improve this query in WordPress, If nested meta_query is not OK?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this problem, filtering rooms with price condition.

User will search for room that has a price of lower than **500** and with **TV** and **cold/hot shower**.

```
Legend:    
rw_prop_price = amount 
rw_prop_rooms1 = checkbox with/without TV
rw_prop_rooms2 = checkbox with/without Tub
rw_prop_rooms3 = checkbox with/without cold/hot shower
```

Here is my code but it doesn't work since its not possible to use nested meta_query.

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'rw_property',
     'posts_per_page' => 10,
     'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
     'relation'=> 'AND', 
     'meta_query' => array(
         'relation' => 'AND', 
            array(
             'key' =>'rw_prop_price',
             'value' => 500, 
             'type' => 'numeric',
             'compare' => '<'  
            ),                                                                      
            array(
               'relation' => 'OR',
                  array(
                    'key' =>'rw_prop_rooms1',
                    'value' => 'yes', 
                    'compare' => '='  
                  ),
                  array(
                    'key' =>'rw_prop_rooms2',
                    'value' => 'no', 
                    'compare' => '='  
                  ),
                  array(
                    'key' =>'rw_prop_rooms3',
                    'value' => 'yes', 
                    'compare' => '='  
                  )
            )                                                                  
        ),                                       
     'post_status' => 'publish'
     );
$wp_query =  new WP_Query( $args );
```

Can anyone help me how can I do this, as much as possible I want to stay using WP_Query of WordPress. But I am willing to restructure my data, I mean if you have a solution like just combine 3 rooms, just serialize etc. as long as it would help me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WP_Query then I think you have to filter by one custom value, save it all to an array, then filter out the ones that don't match the search criteria. Make sure to query for the meta value that will give you the least hits on average (to minimize load from PHP). This may or may not be a good idea depending on how much data you are fetching, but here's an example:

#### Query

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'rw_property',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'meta_query' => array(
         'relation' => 'AND', 
            array(
             'key' =>'rw_prop_price',
             'value' => 500, 
             'type' => 'numeric',
             'compare' => '<'  
            )
     ),                                    
     'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$wp_query =  new WP_Query( $args );
```

#### Filter

```
$results = array();

# Set these values based on user input (search filter settings)
$tv = 'yes';
$hot_tub = 'no';
$shower = 'yes';

# Iterate through all the posts, and select only the ones that match our criteria 
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    
    if( 
        get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rw_prop_rooms1', true ) == $tv &&
        get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rw_prop_rooms2', true ) == $hot_tub &&
        get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rw_prop_rooms3', true ) == $shower
    )
    
    # Store the post object if criteria matches
    $results[] = $wp_query;
    
endwhile;
```

#### Presentation

```
foreach( $results as $post ) 
    echo $post->post_title;
```

This is completely untested, so no guarantee that the code will run. Also, it will ruin your pagination, which I guess is could be a problem in your case (you'll have to build your own pagination). But this is how you need to go about it, I think, if you want to compare a lot of custom values on WordPress.